# Error running pod install how to solve this? I want to start my project with Xcode simulator on m1

Tags: flutter

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401

Error running pod install

Comment: Are you trying to install some specific pod which requires API authorization in  .netrc  for e.g. Mapbox

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install Mapbox-iOS-SDK i guess this might help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66345247/11345007